# Pandas read_pickle breaks because of missing/oudated module

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, modulenotfounderror

I implemented a small simulation environment and have been saving my evaluation results as Pandas data frames in the form of pickle files.

Later, to analyze the results, I have a Jupyter notebooks, where I use Panda's `df = pd.read_pickle(path)` to load the data frames again and visualize the data.
I also annotated metadata as attributes of the data frames, using `df.attr`, which are loaded correctly afterwards.

This used to work fine. Unfortunately, my simulator has evolved and the corresponding Python package changed names, which leads to problems when trying to read old results.
Now, `pd.read_pickle()` still works fine for newly generated results.
But for old results it breaks with a `ModuleNotFoundError`, telling me that it doesn't find the `simulator_old` module, i.e., the previous version of the package with the old name.

I'm not sure why and where the dependency on my package comes from. Maybe I wrote some object from the old package as data frame attribute. I can't figure it out because it always simply breaks.
I want to be able to read old and new results and have `pd.read_pickle()` simply skip any entries that it cannot read but read everything else.

Is there anything like that that I can do to recover my old results? E.g., to tell pickle to ignore such errors?

Comment: Can you not install the old package with the old name?

Comment: Yes, but always just either the new or the old package. The problem is the following naming: `mypackage.old_module` was renamed to `mypackage.new_module`. So when I activate the old package, I can read the old results but not the new ones and vice versa. But I'd like to read and analyze both together.

Comment: I think I found the problem: There's indeed some package object in the data frame attributes, which causes the error when loading with the wrong package version. The only solution I currently see is loading all old results with the old package installed, deleting the package-dependent attribute and saving them again. Without that attribute, I can load the pickle just fine with any version. Or is there a more elegant way to tell pickle to simply ingore some attrs?